# Generate Signed APK grayed out in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, apk

I have the files and .Gradle from eclipse (developer sent them to me) and have the .Gradle on Android Studio. When i go to (build/Generate Signed APK) that button is grayed out all i have changed is the build version and the name.

Would there be a better option for me to edit the app instead of using the .Gradle i have all the files but never used android studio or eclipse before.

Comment: It's Gradle not "gradel", and what have you tried from command line?